# Seeking Excel formula for assigning values to letters

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I assign a number value to letters and then get the average in Excel eg. A=5, B=4, C=3

Comment: Would you be OK with A=65, B=66, …?

Comment: Would you be OK with a=97, b = 98, …?

Comment: If so, [CODE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CODE-function-c32b692b-2ed0-4a04-bdd9-75640144b928)("A") = 65, CODE("a") = 97, *et cetera*.  If you want both A and a to be 65, CODE([UPPER](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/UPPER-function-c11f29b3-d1a3-4537-8df6-04d0049963d6)("A")) = CODE(UPPER("a")) = 65.  Or you can use CODE([LOWER](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOWER-function-3f21df02-a80c-44b2-afaf-81358f9fdeb4)("A")) = CODE(LOWER("a")) = 97

Comment: If you really want A=5, B=4, *et cetera*, you can use 70 - CODE("A")

Answer (score 3):

I would add a column (it can be hidden) which does a vlookup against a new worksheet or range where the letters are cross-referenced to the values you want.  This column would contain the resulting numbers, and could be averaged.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the range is `B4:B8`, use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(102-CODE(LOWER(B4:B8)))/ROWS(B4:B8)
```

to get the average, for example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be through an `IF` statement and an `AVERAGE`. E.g.:

```
=IF(A2="A",5, IF(A2="B",4, IF(A2="C",3, IF(A2="D",2, IF(A2="F",1,"")))))
```

Then

```
=AVERAGE(B2:B10)
```